# Can i restore PDB from rman backup to another CDB?

Tags: oracle, multi-tenant

For example, i made a backup of pdb and i need to restore pdb at this state to another cdb.Is it possible,and how can i make it if it is possible?**Not using clone pdb.**

Comment: What version? Why not using clone pdb? One would think it could use the existing backup ….

Comment: 19.3  ,about clone using backup,i ve never heard about it before ,and it d be good if you explain it

Comment: The documentation explains a lot https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/bradv/rman-duplicating-databases.html#GUID-102FF47A-63D1-45CA-8C9F-4257E16BCA52 It is not literally stated that a backup based PDB clone will work but it is stated database backups in general are a valid source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs don’t explicitly say it is possible in this combination. What the docs do tell is that a backup based clone is always valid.
The reason why many choose for live db clones is that there is less hassle with shared storage for the backup.